# What is javax.xml.bind?

Tags: java, xml, oop, computer-science

I'm very new to exception handling, and while writing this program for school I had some strange errors come up.

In my program I had a class for "ValidationException" which extends "Exception", and 3 other classes.

In one of the classes several of the methods throw to the "ValidationException" class, and in the other class I have several try and catch blocks where they catch a "ValidationException".

Anyways, in the catch statements it wouldn't allow me to put "catch(ValidationException e)", it forced me to put "catch(javax.xml.bind.ValidationException e)".

After doing this it worked just fine. The exact same thing happened with my j-unit test cases.

Anyways, I'm just wondering if I screwed something up somehow! If anyone might have an idea what caused this or what this javax.xml.bind is that would be great!

Comment: Whichever code responsible for throwing the exception was throwing `javax.xml.bind.ValidationException`and not your custom `ValidationException`. You probably got something wrong during imports.

Comment: You just confirmed my biggest worry! I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: "I have no idea how to fix this" - 99% of your life as a programmer right there. You'll know how to fix it once you learn about what's causing it. Right now you feel overwhelmed because you're new to everything and it seems like there's so much, but you'll get a handle on it.

Comment: Just check the imports. There should be a import for the `javax.xml.bind.ValidationException` which is wrong. In this case, remove the import and enter the correct one point to your class.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback! Turns out I had to put the packagename.ValidationException for it to work properly

Answer (score 2):

Problem was collision of class names.  Within your code, your custom ValidationException was in scope by default, thereby masking the ValidationException class within javax.xml.bind package.  Since the thrown exception is a different ValidationException class than in scope, you were simply required to identify the correct package.  Had you named your class MyValidationException, you would not have had to specify the package prefix within the catch.

Think of "package" as being similar to "path" to the specific class or set of classes.